# I'm trying to do the golden ratio with fibonacci

Tags: c

I'm trying to do the golden ratio with fibonacci but I get the error that the integral goes to zero

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int fibonacci (double n){
    if (n==0 || n==1)
        return n;
    else
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
}
double fibonacci_golden_ratio(int n){
    double phi;
    phi = fibonacci(n) / (double) fibonacci(n-1);
    return phi;
}
int main(){
    int i;
    for (i=1;;i++){
        printf ("F = %d ",fibonacci(i));
        printf ("phi = %.5lf \n", fibonacci_golden_ratio(i));
        if ( fabs (fibonacci_golden_ratio(i) - fibonacci_golden_ratio(i-1)) < 0.0001 )
           break;
    }
    printf ("phi = %.5lf\n", fibonacci_golden_ratio(i));
    getch();
}
```

how can i run the code perfectly

Comment: Change `for (i=1;` to `for (i=2;` and think about why it does not work when `i` is 1. What does `fibonacci_golden_ratio(i-1)` do? Before you post a question like this to Stack Overflow, you should either step through the program in a debugger or insert `printf` statements to show what it is doing at each step.

Comment: You're passing doubles to `fibonacci` and returning an `int`.  If anything, that's backwards.  Ideally they'd all be integers.  The only reason for using doubles would be to extend the range of the *result*, not the argument, since the result grows exponentially.

Comment: Optimization hint: Your code evaluates fibonacci for every iteration twice! An one more time for printing the result! It's very redundant. `int a=1, b=1;double phi=0; for (;;) { double prev=phi; phi = (double)b/a; if (fabs(phi-prev)<0.0001) break; int t=a+b; a=b; b=t;} printf("%f\n", phi);`